# How to get different ad users list using same enterprise application?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory, devops

I Have 3 Azure AD (TestAad1, TestAad2, TestAad3).

and Have one App-Registration (AppReg1)

I added this app registration as an Enterprise application to these AADs.

Query: Is there any API or way to get all users of these AADs using this App-Registration (AppReg1)?

As like getting users from the same aad,

> https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users

Comment: Have you already checked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/howto-convert-app-to-be-multi-tenant ?

Comment: Checked this already.

Comment: Azure AD provide the option to create a multi-tenant app, but it doesn't mean you can use this application to get users from any tenant. A multi-tenant app can be used as an Enterprise application and you must have to let other tenant admin to [consent this enterprise application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/manage-apps/grant-admin-consent?pivots=portal#construct-the-url-for-granting-tenant-wide-admin-consent) to register in their tenant. Then you can follow the steps posted below to call graph api for each tenant to get the user.

Comment: Already everything is done you describe here. but other AADs have no app registration as they use enterprise applications to let their user log in to the client app. so I can't do below steps for other AADs.

Answer (score 1):

I have done this for one single-tenant app, which will probably be similar to a multitenant app. Assume that you have set up your app registration correctly as a Multitenant app.

The high-level idea is to grant your app registration to access the GraphAPI scope `User.Read.All`.

1. Go to the app registration page -> API permissions -> Add a permission -> Find Mirscrsoft Graph API -> select Application Permissions -> User.Read.All. You must click on `grant admin consent for your organisation`.
2. Create a client secret on the app registration page -> Certificates & secrets. Click `New client secret`, then make a copy of the secret value. (You cannot see it once it's saved).
3. Now test that you can get the access token from Microsoft by calling the following request with three parameters `tenant id`, `client id` and `client secret`:

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<one of your tenants>/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1 
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded  
client_id=<your app registration client id>
&client_secret=<your app registration client secret>
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&grant_type=client_credentials
&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com
```

4. Get the access token from the response, then make a request to the GraphAPI:

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/
Authorization: Bearer eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJub2...
```

Hope this will give you some ideas.

Comment: I already did this & getting users for TestAad1 not getting other AADs users. FYI other AADs have no any app-registration.

Comment: You have to register and apply consent in any tenant that should use your app.

Comment: consented also. Now I need all users of TestAad2, TestAad3. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried admin consent for TestAad2 and TestAad3 by using this URL `https://login.microsoftonline.com/organizations/v2.0/adminconsent?client_id=<your client id>&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default`. Choose an admin account from Aad2 and Aad3 respectively.

Comment: @CharlesHan Thanks for the comment. Yes did this already.